# Adding values of a dictionary to a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, github

Hi guys I have a function collect metrics which basically calls two functions get_open_prs() and calculate_warnings()

```
def collect_metrics():
                """function for collecting the desired metrics from github"""
                for owner,repo in config.REPOS_TO_CHECK:
                    pulls_url = get_open_prs(owner,repo)
                    desired_github_metrics = calculate_warnings(pulls_url, config.TOO_OLD_DAYS)
                    desired_github_metrics["owner"] = owner
                    desired_github_metrics["repo"] = repo
                    print desired_github_metrics #prints dictionary
if __name__ == "__main__":

    collect_metrics()
```

now the output that I get when I print collect_metrics() is:

```
{'owner': 'owner', 'repo': 'test_repo', 'days': 7}
{'owner': 'owner1', 'repo': 'test_repo1', 'days': 17}
```

what I want to do is to return desired_github_metrics instead of printing it, and I want that output as dictionary inside of a list:

```
desired output:

    [{'owner': 'owner', 'repo': 'test_repo', 'days': 7}]
    [{'owner': 'owner1', 'repo': 'test_repo1', 'days': 17}]
```

so that when I call collect_metrics functions:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
        data = collect_metrics()
        for my data in data:
            print(datum) 

#prints output
        [{'owner': 'owner', 'repo': 'test_repo', 'days': 7}]
        [{'owner': 'owner1', 'repo': 'test_repo1', 'days': 17}]
```

Comment: Do you just want to output them inside a list or change them to be inside a list?

Comment: I want to output them inside a list. so when I return GitHub_desired_metrics, I get output as

[{'owner': 'owner', 'repo': 'test_repo', 'days': 7}]
[{'owner': 'owner1', 'repo': 'test_repo1', 'days': 17}]

Comment: then you have to do `print(list(datum))`. Also may i ask why you just want them to print them as a list? I does not change anything

Comment: Your desired output has two lists, each containing one dict.  Is this really what you want?  A single list containing all the dicts seems much better.

Comment: John I want the output as two lists, I have written my test cases that way. can you help me out. I basically want to return gitHub_collect_metrics, and when I call it it returns the output

Comment: There's no way to return two separate lists from a function.  You can return a list that _contains_ two other lists, but that's not quite the same thing.

Comment: John cool, could you tell me how to use the concept of a single list containing all the dicts. that you mentioned above

Comment: At the top of your function, declare an empty list.  At the bottom of your loop, append the `desired_github_metrics` dictionary to your list.  At the end of the function, return the list.

Comment: John it didnt work, my desired_github_metrics basically prints two dictionaries, because in the for loop config.repos_to_check I have specified two repos, so if I specify 10 repos there 10 dictionaries will be printed out the reason I am not returning it there is, if I return desired_github_metrics only the first dictionary will be printed from the loop, what I want is to return the desired_github_metrics and when I call it using the for loop like data = collect_metrics()  I get all the returned values as dictionaries enclosed in a list

Comment: You have to create the list before the for loop `lst=[] for owner,repo in config.REPOS_TO_CHECK: ` then you append them after `desired_github_metrics["repo"] = repo` `lst.append(desired_github_metrics)` after the for loop you can now `print(lst)`

Comment: John worked perfectly, thanks a lot, figured it out, what you said was spot on.